# Voyager admin menu isn't shown for user with role "admin" with all permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I've created new user by regular "Register" link at app frontend, then issued

```
php artisan voyager:admin this_user@mail.com
```

and logged in to Voyager with this user's login and password. What I saw is empty space in the panel on the left instead of admin menu:
[image]

I've checked roles and permissions in database. In `users` table this user has `role_id` set to `1`, which is "admin" in table `roles` and has all permissions in `permission_role`. This seems to be OK.

Why this user doesn't see the admin menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that two tables were missing from the database: `data_rows` and `data_types`. I've recreated them using this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_types` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `display_name_singular` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `display_name_plural` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `model_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `policy_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `controller` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `generate_permissions` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `server_side` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `data_types_name_unique` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `data_types_slug_unique` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data_rows` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `required` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `browse` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `edit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `add` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data_rows_data_type_id_foreign` (`data_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `data_rows_data_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`data_type_id`) REFERENCES `data_types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then I've seeded them by issuing commands:

```sh
php artisan db:seed --class=DataTypesTableSeeder
php artisan db:seed --class=DataRowsTableSeeder
```

Now everything is working fine!